# Is it possible to alter the placement of Wii Channels?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I have enough channels on my Wii now that they have spilled over to a second page.  It's very cumbersome to have to move to that second page to access those channels when there are other channels on the first page that I use very infrequently.  Can I move the channels around, or am I stuck with their current layout?

Comment: Also, you can use the plus and minus buttons to quickly changes pages on the Wii homescreen. The plus button will move one page to the right, the minus button will move one page to the left.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, press "A" and "B" to "pinch" the channel, and you can move it wherever you want (except for the Disc Channel).

Comment: Just beat me to it.

Comment: note that this won't work for the Disc Channel

Comment: It actually will work for the Disc Channel with the proper homebrew modifications.

Answer (score 1):

As well as reordering the channels you can move them to an SD card. The Wii will take up to an 8GB SD card for this, but some games that save content to SD cards won't recognise such a large card. Check each game for the maximum size card it supports.

Some will even run from the SD card, but others have to be copied back to the Wii to be run.